# Is there anyway to write LaTex algorithm in sphinx-doc?

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to write [algorithm in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Algorithms) in Sphinx-doc? Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an extension [sphinxcontrib-pseudocode](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-pseudocode/) that allows one to write LaTeX algorithm via [algpseudocode](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Algorithms) LaTeX package syntax directly inside sphinx-doc. The extension is powered by [pseudocode.js](https://github.com/SaswatPadhi/pseudocode.js) behind the scene.